# Responsive slider issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

Slider images are not shown on the desktop, tablet and mobile screen, but other single images are shown perfectly on every screen.
Here is the link: http://shakil.comuv.com/odesk1/

Comment: You download a library and now you expect us to debug it? People here are ready to help you with any programming problems - maybe even to find a bug in your code - but not to debug third-party software. Please contact the software provider.

Answer (score 0):

you have some missing files:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

this is loading another file from you host, which causes the issue

```
Date: 19/08/2014 12:29:09 a.m.
Error: SyntaxError: syntax error
Source File: http://shakil.comuv.com/odesk1/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
Line: 1
Source Code:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//E
```

on the other hand, you were calling JQuery twice, so delete this line and it should work fine